# Popup button not visible when the splitview is in portrait orientation

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I've added another Storyboard for the iPad to my app, trying to make my first universal app.

I'm starting up with a UISplitViewController where I have a menu on the left and the detail controller on the right.

I've customized the navigation bar in the detail view and now the popup button (the one that should show the menu when the iPad is in portrait orientation) does not show.

This is the code I'm using to customize the navigation bar in viewDidLoad:

```
UIImage *navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBarImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
self.navBar.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];
```

Then, in the delegate method for the split view "willHideViewController", I'm trying to customize the Menu button:

```
UIImage *menuBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"];
menuBtn = [menuBtn resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 4.5, 0.0, 4.5)];
barButtonItem.image = menuBtn;
barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Menu", nil);
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
```

I've tried to remove the navigation bar and menu button customizations and the button shows up.
What's wrong with my code?

EDIT:

Following Nazir's advice, I've added the following code to my viewDidLoad method:

```
UIImage *menuBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"];
menuBtn = [menuBtn resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 4.5, 0.0, 4.5)];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:menuBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@""];
```

I forgot that button didn't need a title, but if I don't set it, the button will not appear.

Now the problem is that I'm messing up something with the Storyboard.
At the app start up I want to see the menu on the left (MasterViewController) and a tableview with some data on the right (DetailViewController).

So the relationship segue connecting the Split View Controller to the Detail View Controller is of type "detail view controller".

Now in the menu, beside all the other options, there's the first option used to go back to the first detail view controller (a kind of "Home" option), so I've also connected the Master View Controller with the Detail View Controller using a "Replace" segue.

So what happens now is that the menu button appears when the orientation is portrait, but if I tap on the "home" option of the menu, the button disappears.

That button is supposed to be visible on all the different detail view controllers that I'm going to create, so it's very important.

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If i got what you want to do - then add background to topBatButton so you could do as:
Do it in DetailViewController.m

```
UIImage *menuBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"];
```

**Setting the image to Bar item:**

`[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:menuBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

**Setting the title to Bar item:**

`[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"sometitle"];`

Comment: I tried both in viewDidLoad and willHideViewController and it's not working.

Comment: Now seems it's working, but I'm messing up something. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a titleView AND a leftBarButton item (if I read the docs right)

As per the docs:

Titleview: "If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title. This property is ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not nil."

SO I assume the inverse is true too

Comment: Is it true only for iPad? Because for the iPhone I use the same code and it works.

Comment: Sorry don't know but splitview is for iPad only anyways so I could imagine differences between the two devices here

Comment: I've tried to comment out the navigationbar's title view, but it's not working yet.